# Is development faster in other kinds of rules compared to democracy?

Tags: democracy, government

Development is important for a country. It has various kinds, varying from economic to technologically. Is it so that development is faster in other kinds of rule compared to democracy?

I mean is there any correlation with rate and type of development versus type of government.

Comment: Please define “development”, and how you want its rate to be measured. Otherwise, the question will not be answerable.

Comment: Development referred here is economic and socio in nature. Talking about the development of country is its growth in various fields.

Comment: Has Canada grown by 5% with regard to culture in the last five years, or perhaps by 12,7%? There is no clear measure.

Comment: Assuming OP means economic development, there is a wealth of literature on this subject. It should be easily answerable even without a specific indicator being added.

Comment: @indigochild: The OP explicitly speaks of “various kinds” of development, “from economic to technologically”.

Comment: The fundamental thing to consider regarding development, is the subject it refers to. For example, Sparta was ruled by a monarch-king and was arguably the most (or second most) developed city-state in ancient Greece. While few spartan citizens, nobles and King's affiliates enjoyed this wealth, the vast majority of the society comprised from Helots=slave workers without any civilian rights and only basic means of survival.